# How do I make these MIPI signals better?

Tags: oscilloscope, differential, debugging, signal-integrity, high-speed

I have a system which transmits 1 Gbps single lane MIPI video over several flex circuits. Where each flex circuit connects to its neighbour, I have placed a MIPI repeater chip: [SNx5DPHY440SS](https://www.ti.com/product/SN75DPHY440SS). At the receiving end is a [Cypress CX3 MIPI to USB chip](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/universal-serial-bus-usb-power-delivery-controller/peripheral-controllers/ez-usb-cx3-programmable-mipi-csi-2-to-usb-3.0-camera-controller/). Each flex circuit is a different length.

At the input and output of each MIPI repeater chip, I have soldered on a 3-pin differential probe point so that I can look at the waveforms. (only one is shown in the diagram below).

[image: MIPI Video transmission over multiple repeaters]

The MIPI repeaters are configured with a 150ps rise time, 220mV output voltage swing, and 2.5dB output pre-emphasis.

At the receiver, the video sometimes drops frames, and sometimes drops out altogether for short periods. I am fairly sure that the culprit is the transmission between the FPGA and the CX3, because if I connect the FPGA to the CX3 directly, then the video is 100% reliable, with no dropped frames in 150 hours.

I am using a Keysight MSOX3104T oscilloscope, which has 1GHz bandwidth and 5GSPS, and an active differential probe with 1.5GHz bandwidth. I realise, of course, that the oscilloscope's bandwidth is pretty borderline for this application, and so I'm not seeing the full picture, but the waveforms seem to be telling me something.

These screenshots show 1ns per division horizontally, and 200mv vertically. What seems odd to me is that the transmit side tends to look worse than the receive side, as if the signal is reflecting off the receivers and bouncing back to the transmitter.

[image: A]
[image: BC]
[image: DE]
[image: FG]
[image: HI]

As you can see, some of these waveforms look fairly decent, while some of them seem to show a lot of ringing, despite the internal termination of the MIPI repeater chips.

Questions:

- What could be causing this ringing if there are terminations in the chips?
- What can I do to try to reduce this ringing, and hopefully remove the dropped frames?

Comment: The bandwidth of your signal is more determined by the rise time than the data rate. The equation I see most for this is $$f_{3db} = \frac{0.35}{\tau_r}$$
In your case this comes out to 2.3 GHz. Also taking into account that the bandwidth limitations of the scope and probes are probably compounding, you are likely missing very large parts of the picture here due to bandwidth limitations. It will be very hard to diagnose without better measurements :(

Comment: I’d look at the design of the flex circuits to verify the expected transmission line performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more careful testing and debugging, here's what I have found.

Firstly, despite the bandwidth of the scope being barely enough for this signal, those traces are actually meaningful, and are telling us something.

Starting with the 'H' trace, it looks considerably worse than the 'I' trace, as if the signal is being reflected at 'I' due to a lack of termination. In fact, this is exactly what was happening. Although the CX3 chip has internal termination, this termination is not enabled until the chip is actively streaming video over USB. When I begin streaming video, this trace suddenly looks a lot better.

Lastly, the 'F' trace, which is the next worst one. While all of the differential pairs are supposed to be 100R differential impedance, it turns out that the FG flex circuit was incorrectly manufactured, and was causing a reflection. We were able to set the scope up to performe some Time Domain Reflectometry, and could see that its impedance was more like 60R. Adding some parallel termination resistance at the receiver inputs improved this signal considerably.